# Route to Internet router from different subnet

Tags: networking, internet, routing

I ran into a situation where my network is setup like the following:

[image: my network]

In this image my Computer A is connected with WiFi DSL router which is connected to the Internet. Computer A and B are directly connected with network interface without any router or switch. I am trying to setup my Computer B so it can access the internet through Computer A. I have a very basic knowledge about networking and my assumption (after bit of research) is that it can be possible by adding correct static route, but I don't know which IP should be added and on which computer. Any help?

Note: My both systems are running Ubuntu.

---

ifconfig of Computer A:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:23:5a:a2:22:04  
          inet addr:192.168.1.17  Bcast:192.168.1.31  Mask:255.255.255.240
          inet6 addr: fe80::223:5aff:fea2:2204/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:323621697 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:90168726 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:487306002830 (487.3 GB)  TX bytes:5958302707 (5.9 GB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:4998 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4998 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:465330 (465.3 KB)  TX bytes:465330 (465.3 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:21:00:dd:78:67  
          inet addr:192.168.1.6  Bcast:192.168.1.15  Mask:255.255.255.240
          inet6 addr: fe80::221:ff:fedd:7867/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:88838 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:10052432
          TX packets:74404 errors:56 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:45915165 (45.9 MB)  TX bytes:12858677 (12.8 MB)
          Interrupt:18
```

ifconfig of Computer B:

```
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=10b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_HWTAGGING,AV>
    ether ac:87:a3:16:3c:ce 
    inet6 fe80::ae87:a3ff:fe16:3cce%en0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4 
    inet 192.168.1.18 netmask 0xfffffff0 broadcast 192.168.1.31
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: autoselect (1000baseT <full-duplex,flow-control>)
    status: active
en1: flags=8823<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 6c:40:08:a7:f1:7e 
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: autoselect (<unknown type>)
    status: inactive
en2: flags=963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX> mtu 1500
    options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 2a:00:00:5e:ee:00 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
en3: flags=963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX> mtu 1500
    options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 2a:00:00:5e:ee:01 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
p2p0: flags=8802<BROADCAST,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 2304
    ether 0e:40:08:a7:f1:7e 
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
awdl0: flags=8902<BROADCAST,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1484
    ether 6a:8a:6e:bb:a5:d4 
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
    ether ae:87:a3:61:0d:00 
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x2
    member: en2 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 6 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en3 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 7 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: <unknown type>
    status: inactive
```

Answer (score 0):

Your A computer need to act as a router in this setup. Uncomment this line

```
#net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

in /etc/sysctl.conf on A. It will turn on forwarding on next system start. And execute

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

to turn on forwarding rihgt now.

With that done you need to set up static route in your dsl router. With your subnets it will look as depicted

[image]

This setting tells your router to route packets destined for 192.168.1.16 subnet via the gateway at 192.168.1.7. Because 1.7 interface is on the routers subnet.

**Update**

Without DHCP, all addresses are fixed
/etc/network/interfaces example on A computer:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.7
    netmask 255.255.255.240
    broadcast 192.168.1.15
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.17
    netmask 255.255.255.240
    broadcast 192.168.1.31
```

/etc/network/interfaces example on B computer:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto en0
iface en0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.18
    netmask 255.255.255.240
    broadcast 192.168.1.31
    gateway 192.168.1.17
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

After that you need to execute

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Comment: I have tried your solution but I can't access internet from my Computer B. I have also tried to ping my router 192.168.1.1 from Computer B and it can't reach it.

Comment: Can you show /etc/network/interfaces content on A?

Comment: I only have these 2 lines on comp A:
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

Comment: Try to change those files like in my update. On A and B. But first, what ifconfig shows?

Comment: Try again the updated part